# Get dictionary data always at fixed position

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I got a dictionary from an api as:

```
book_data = {'book name':'abc','author name':'john doe','book version':'12','book number':'19','book price':'200'}
```

I only want the data of 'book name', 'author name' and 'book price', for this I did,

```
filtered_book_data = {key: book_data[key] for key in book_data.keys() & {"book name", "author name", "book price"}}
```

But while printing, filtered_book_data,

it prints either :

```
{'book name' : 'abc', 'author name' : 'john doe', 'book price' : '200'} or
{'author name' : 'john doe' 'book name' : 'abc' , 'book price' : '200'} or
{'book price' : '200' , 'author name' : 'john doe' 'book name' : 'abc' } or so on
```

But it's not fixes, but I want the O/P to be always:

```
{'book name' : 'abc', 'author name' : 'john doe', 'book price' : '200'}
```

book name, author name, book price always in that order.

How can I fix the position of dictionary?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? You can still access all the values.

Comment: @BuddyBob because I want to render the data always in that order at frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reorganize it like this. It uses a reference list.

```
order = ['book name','author name','book price']
weird = {'book price' : '200' , 'author name' : 'john doe', 'book name' : 'abc' } 
good = {k:weird.get(k) for k in order}
```

Comment: Thank you so much..this is exactly what i wanted..:)